# unhandled exception Directory import not supported resolving ES modules imported from architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ionic-framework, ionic-cli

**An unhandled exception occurred: Directory import '\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from \node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js**

*Did you mean to import /node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/dev-server/index.js?
[ng] See "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-vVgkqZ\angular-errors.log" for further details.
[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 127).*

Answer (score 1):

**Check the NPM packages installed and also check dependencies also installed correctly**

*Run **"npm audit fix --force"** once or twice and again try to run the project*

> It worked for me I hope works for u also